# Incorporating text into a patterned background

Tags: text, patterns

I am working on an invitation for print and have been coming up short with a good way to incorporate text into the piece. Here is the background I am working with:

[image: Invitation Background]

What I am trying to do is place text into the "free" space below the seal, but I haven't been able to find any good examples for incorporating text into a background with dots like this.

I tried simply carving out a space for the text, but that looked too unnatural. I also tried placing another seal/ribbon to contain the text, but that cluttered the page too much and I really want the focal point to be the seal. The text will be a quote/verse that is meant to compliment the rest of the piece.

Does anybody have any suggestions or examples where text has been worked into a pattern like this? Are there any standards or general guidelines for something along these lines? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Contrast/Color**. If the text contrasts against the pattern well enough you may not need to pull any "tricks" or special appearance items. Text the color of the dots shouldn't present any real issue provided....

**Size**. The size of the text will play a large factor. If your text has strokes and counters the same, or relatively the same, size as the dots in the pattern that will cause visual confusion. However, if the text strokes and counters are much larger than the pattern dots there should be no issue.

You have not provided enough information to more accurately address your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Inkscape

- creating a text box
- duplicate it as background (bg)
- with bg I did

  - change color
  - grow (outset)
  - added some transparency
  - added some blur

And this what it looks like:

[image: solution with Inkscape]

This is a sketch only, so the relation between size, transparency and blur of the text background are far from being perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an "opinionated" question; wich is not ideal for GD. But I would suggest make the text wholly or partly transparent, but with a shadow only. You could get something like this (but with your pattern "shining" through.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also opt to use a simpler aspect of the centerpiece to frame/partially frame the section where you want to put the text. That way the circle remains the centerpiece but the text is somewhat decorated without being too busy. Rather than deleting the dots from inside the frame you could tone them back by dropping the opacity though that may not be needed as Scott has already mentioned.
Here is a brief example, naturally positioning, frame size, font size/colour are all a matter of preference and dependent on the layout of the verse.

[image]

Good luck with this.